# Unable to Print Matched Sed Regex

Tags: shell, sed

I've got a file task.md and I am trying to print a line from that file.

When I use pretty much any regex tester I am able to caputure the line that I need, so I suspect I'm using sed incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
## Todo

- Task 3

## Doing

- Task 2

## Done

- Task 1
```

Using `## Doing[\r\n]+- ([^\r\n]+)` matches `Task 2`, but trying something like

```sh
sed -n '/## Doing[\r\n]+- ([^\r\n]+)/p' task.md
```

does not get me my expected result.

I've searched around, but either have not understood a particular answer, or couldn't find one.

Comment: `awk '/Doing/{found=1;next} found && NF>1 {print $0;exit}' file`?

Comment: Or `awk '/##\s+Doing/{found=1;next} found && NF>1 {print $0;exit}' file`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've not used a lot of awk. Time to learn I suppose. The first comment seems to work the second didn't not sure why, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: `awk` is by far the best "Swiss Army Knife" of text processing available. It is actually not bad. The biggest hurdle to get over is that an `awk` script made up of rules you write. Each rule will be applied in order to each record (line) of input. There are two special rules `BEGIN` (applied before the actual processing starts -- let's you assign variables or write out a header row) and the `END` rule that runs after all records are processed (output summaries, averages, footer, etc..) [GNU Awk Users Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is good.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: If you look at the comment, there are 2-rules, `/##\s+Doing/{found=1;next}` if the line contains `##(whitespace)Doing` then set `found=1` and skip to the `next` record. The second rule `found && NF>1 {print $0;exit}` if `found` not zero and the number of fields is greater than `1`, print the record and exit (`$0` refers to the whole record, `$1` the first field, `$2` the second, etc...)

Comment: As for why your sed wasn't working: In it's dialect of regular expressions, Posix Basic, + and parentheses are normal characters, not RE metacharacters.